# Impossible to build document with biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

As of today, I have not been able to build any documents using the `biblatex-chicago` class. MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Saussure1995,
Author = {Ferdinand de Saussure},
Origyear = {1916},
Publisher = {Payot},
Title = {Cours de Linguistique G{\'e}n{\'e}rale},
Year = {1995}}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\autocite{Saussure1995}    

\end{document}
```

Running `latexmk -cd -e -f -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 myfile.tex`

produces the following error:

```
 Undefined control sequence.
\cms@choose ->\ifblx@load@version@one 
                                      nty\else cms\fi 
l.40 \begin{document}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

The MWE works without problems if I substitute `biblatex` for `biblatex-chicago`.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: This compiles fine for me on a TL 2015 system. Have you deleted all your aux files and tried again?  What happens when you run the pieces separately, i,e., run pdflatex then biber then pdflatex?

Comment: Deleting all temp files (including `.aux`) does not resolve the issue. Running manually breaks at step one (pdflatex), with the same error message.

Comment: It seems due to the new `biblatex` version. :(

Comment: @egreg Yes, I just updated and now it fails for me too.

Comment: Please be aware that the new `biblatex` version has changed the name formatting commands in a way that will cause no errors with `biblatex-chicago`, but some name definitions will be ignored silently. Do check your output for CMS compliance.

Comment: Oops... Not what I wanted to hear a few weeks before filing a dissertation, but thanks for the heads up. Is there a repository to download an older version of `biblatex` from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `biblatex-chicago` package has been updated to version 0.9.9h 2016-03-22.

According to the package documentation, this update specifically addresses incompatibilities with `biblatex`, version 3.3.

The `biblatex-chicago` package is now available through CTAN:
http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago

Answer (score 15):

This is caused by a change in the `biblatex` test for an old system. The previous conditional was called `\ifblx@load@version@one` and is used in the `biblatex-chicago` style.  The new conditional is called `\ifblx@load@version@legacy`.  You can temporarily solve the problem in the following way by adding the following to your preamble, after loading `biblatex`.

```
\makeatletter
\def\cms@choose{cms}
\makeatother
```

A more general solution is given in Herbert's answer:

```
\makeatletter
\let\ifblx@load@version@one\ifblx@load@version@legacy
\makeatother
```

But a long term solution to the problem will be a fix to `biblatex-chicago`.

Answer (score 10):

Write into the preamble:

```
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\makeatletter
\let\ifblx@load@version@one\ifblx@load@version@legacy
\makeatother
```