# Biblatex style biblatex-philosophy fails to compile with "Undefined control sequence. \ifblx@load@version@legacy"

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-philosophy

I can no longer compile documents with the `biblatex-philosophy` style for the citations and references.

The document does not compile at all, and I get the following message

```
Undefined control sequence \ifblx@load@version@legacy
```

and several

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \blx@defformat@d.
```

I have tried googling the problem, and only come across something about a year ago relating to a texlive or biblatex update.

Here is a minimal example that fails to compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=philosophy-classic,bibstyle=philosophy-classic]{biblatex}
%   \bibliography{References.bib}
\begin{document}
% \maketitle
Text.
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this to compile documents with the `biblatex-philosophy` style?

Comment: Works fine for me in a current texlive 2016 and `File: philosophy-classic.bbx 2016/11/26 v1.9 A set of styles for biblatex`. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: I can confirm that version `2016/11/26 v1.9` of `philosophy-classic` runs in your MWE as well as an extended document without problems together with `biblatex` 3.7. I strongly suspect that you are using an outdated version of `biblatex-philsophy`, you need to update the package to the current version either with `tlmgr` (TeX live) or the 'MikTeX Update' tool in both Admin and User mode.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem was an old version of biblatex-philosophy. I'm using openSUSE Tumbleweed, so assumed that all texlive packages are up to date, but biblatex-philosophy is still at v1.3! Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is no longer present in the current version of [`biblatex-philosophy`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-philosophy) (1.9 dated 2016-11-26). So you should update the package in your TeX distribution. When you update the package, make sure to update the `biblatex` package and Biber along with `biblatex-philosophy` to avoid version conflicts.

`\ifblx@load@version@legacy` is an outdated and no longer supported way to check if BibTeX or Biber is used as `backend`. See also [Impossible to build document with biblatex-chicago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298398/35864).

The error `\blx@defformat@d` appears if one needs pre-3.3 code to modify the name format with `biblatex` version >=3.3. See [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864).