# Repeated Author First Name BibLaTex Chicago

Tags: luatex, biblatex-chicago, texlive-2016

After updating to 2016 TexLive (Mac) from 2015 TeXLive (Mac), the BibLaTeX Chicago package (`biblatex-chicago`), when compiled with LuaLaTeX, repeats the author first name 3 times in the same entry in the bibliography.  If I switch back to 2015 TeXLive (Mac), author first names display correctly.

Below is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{utced.bib}

@BOOK{henson_life_1849,
  title = {The Life of Josiah Henson},
  publisher = {Arthur D. Phelps},
  year = {1849},
  author = {Henson, Josiah},
  date = {1849},
  location = {Boston},
  shorttitle = {The Life of Josiah Henson}
}

@BOOK{stowe_key_1853,
  title = {A Key to \textup{Uncle Tom's Cabin}: Presenting the Original
Facts and Documents},
   publisher = {Boston: John P. Jewett \& Co.; Cleveland, Ohio: Jewett, Proctor \&
Worthington},
  year = {1853},
  author = {Stowe, Harriet Beecher},
  date = {1853},
  pagetotal = {280},
  shorttitle = {A Key to \textup{Uncle Tom's Cabin}}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{utced.bib}


\begin{document}
\title{Chicago Citation Style with BibLaTeX}
\author{Wesley Raabe}
\maketitle

\section{Sample}

found him true and square\footnote{The \textit{Life of Josiah Henson} (1849), a slave narrative, is cited by Stowe as one of the models for Shelby's enslaved man Tom. (\cite[26]{stowe_key_1853};  \cite[13]{henson_life_1849}).} in everything."

\pagebreak
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I believe the problem is related to matters described in these two questions.
[Impossible to build document with biblatex-chicago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298398/impossible-to-build-document-with-biblatex-chicago)

But I have updated. When I try to compile in TeXLive 2016 (Mac), all packages updated, I have to add the following workaround to make it compile:

```
\makeatletter
\def\cms@choose{cms}
\makeatother
```

But it issues the following error messages:

```
Undefined control sequence. \abx@macro@name:given-family ...}{#2#3#1}\if empty
        {#2}{}
{\mkbibnamegiven {#2...
```

I can force it to ignore all error messages, but then the name problem happens, as below.

[image]

I delete the AUX files between compile attempts. Also, `tlmgr info` says `biblatex-chicago` is on version `cat-date:    2016-06-10 17:15:51 +0200`, the latest, so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! When did you most recently update MacTeX2016? The reason I ask is that I can't replicate the issue you are encountering on a fully updated MacTeX system. I have `biblatex-chicago 2016/06/01 v 3.4` and `biblatex 2016/12/05 v3.7`. Version of `biber`: 2.7.

Comment: I downloaded MacTeX2016 on January 19, 2017 and updated packages 3 or 4 days later.

Comment: `biblatex 2016-12-06 v. 3.7` `biber 2016-09-08 v. 2.6` and `biblatex chicago 2016-06-10` not sure about version, does not display on `tlmgr info biblatex-chicago` Maybe it's the Biber version?

Comment: Can you update `biber`?

Comment: Not sure. In TeXLive utility, I assume I'd just do `Reinstall selected packages`.

Comment: `Reinstall selected packages` does not work. Still version 2.6. `tlmgr update --list` does not show `biber` as an updatable package.

Comment: Can you open a command window and type `sudo tlmgr update --self --all`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53031/discussion-between-english-prof-wraabe-and-mico).

Answer (score 3):

The immediate problem, repeated name, appears to have been repaired by one of the following steps (not sure which)

1. Removing old installations, 2009-2014, advised by Mico.
2. Running `FixLink.pkg`,
3. Removing `tex-mf local`, which had `tex/latex/biblatex-contrib` (Apr. 2016) and `tex/latex/bibtex` (Dec. 2014).

However, Biber still shows two versions, 2.6 on `tlmgr info` but 2.7 on `biber-v`. A configuration conflict from old installations appears to be the likely cause.

Unsure if related, but packages `fontenc`, `inputenc` and `lmodern` (sample MWE) not compatible with LuaLaTeX. Use `fontspec` instead.